# how can anotherString.value work in source code of the class String in java?

Tags: java, string

Recently I viewed the source code of the class String in Java. And I find that like XXX.value appears frequently. Like this:

```
    public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
        int len1 = value.length;
        int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;

            int k = 0;
            while (k < lim) {
            char c1 = v1[k];
            char c2 = v2[k];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                return c1 - c2;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    }
```

But the value[] is declared in this way:

```
private final char value[];
```

The value[] is private from the above and How can anotherString.value work?

Comment: this is within the String class itself, so it can read private class variables.

Answer (score 2):

OOP specifies that private objects are private to the class.

The private modifier enforces Encapsulation principle.

The idea is that 'outer world' should not make changes to String internal processes because String implementation may change over time (and you would have to change the whole outer world to fix the differences in implementation - which is nearly to impossible).

When instance of String accesses internals of other String instance - you can be sure that both instances always know the details of implementation of String. If the logic of internal to String processes is changed - all you have to do is change the code of String.